# Allow udisksctl loop-setup without authentication for specific users

Tags: linux, testing, polkit, udisks

I have some tests that verify the behavior of a program under conditions where it runs out of disk space.  Previously I've used `dd` to create a small-ish file then `mkfs` to make a filesystem on it, then used `sudo losetup` to mount it as a loopback device, then run my test (note, `/dev/full` is not appropriate here: the test makes lots of files in a directory and it needs to start with space, then run out).

But now I'm moving into a CI/CD environment where I don't have any `sudo` access for the account that will be running the tests so I need an alternative.

I discovered `udisksctl` with `loop-setup` which works great on my system, but when I run it on the CI/CD systems I still get authorization errors: reading more closely it requires the user to be logged in, so a remote service doesn't appear sufficient.

While I can't get full sudo access I could probably install a polkit exception to allow this account to manage loopback devices.  I see `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.UDisks2.policy` with various sections on managing loopback and I've read a number of SO questions that just say edit this file and allow `any`, which is probably not great.

I've not been able to suss out exactly what to do here, is there some way to add a new file into `/etc/polkit-1/localuthority` somewhere for example that will allow me to specify that a specific user can manage loopback devices without `sudo`, without a login session (coming in over SSH, for example, or, in this case, invoked from a `systemd` service with a `User=` setting)?

Or is this method of testing this situation just too complicated and there's something else people would recommend that would be simpler?

Answer (score 0):

First I created a file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/55-storage.pkla` with following content:

```
[Storage Permissions]
Identity=unix-group:disk
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.loop-setup;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
ResultAny=yes
```

Note that in the above `loop-setup` allows you to use the `loop-setup` and `loop-free` subcommands of `udisksctl`, whereas `filesystem-mount` allows you to run `mount` and `unmount`.

Then I did:

```
usermod -aG disk someuser
systemctl restart polkit.service
```

Now, when `someuser` runs `udisksctl loop-setup -f my-iso.iso`, it works without demanding a password. I'm doing all of this over SSH.

This is on Ubuntu 20.04, so the exact steps may be different for another distribution.

**Acknowledgement**: [This SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/708032/) was very helpful in working out how to do the above.